# how to save the output of scp command?

Tags: scp, debug

I want to save the output of scp command each a laps of time, in fact we i make scp --debug , I see the progressive rate of transferring file .
I want to save each time (1s exp) the output of the command.

Comment: Save to a text file? Different file each time? Why do you need that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the script command:

```
script -c "scp filename username@hostname:/directory"
```

That will save all output to a file called typescript.  Since scp updates the progress meter once every second, the typescript file will show a line for each second that the progress meter was updated.